# cannot find Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ddms

I'm new to android development and trying to install my first hello world app to a phone vis USB and getting Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device 'HT0A6PY04566': timeout

So after searching it seems I should try to increase the timeout as per the instructions in the question title.

However I cannot find where to set DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout

I am running ADT V22.6.2 and have never used this or eclipse before. I'm running Ubuntu 14

I did get to the DDMS screen via Window > Open Perspective > Other > DDMS, can see my phone listed, but cannot find any timeout setting. I'm sure I've gone blind!

Thank you.

EDIT - found setting! Changed  timeout to 30 seconds, still getring same error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now, tried another USB port on PC, someone here mentioned that some ports supply more power than others. I also have a really cheap 3 meter long cable so maybe a shorter/better cable is in order